# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist - in clean function of the model

Tags: django

I have model

```
@with_author
class Lease(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    is_renewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    is_terminated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %i %s ' % ("lease#", self.id, self.unit)

    def clean(self):
        model = self.__class__
        if self.unit and (self.is_active == True)  and model.objects.filter(unit=self.unit, is_terminated = False , is_active = True).count() == 1:
            raise ValidationError('Unit has active lease already, Terminate existing one prior to creation of new one or create a not active lease '.format(self.unit))
```

and I have a form

```
class LeaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LeaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['unit'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = Lease
        fields = [  'unit',
        'is_active','is_renewed', 'description']
```

and each time a save this form without selecting value for unit I am getting

> error RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

from my clean function in model since there is no `self.unit`

but I am explicitly validating the unit field.(at least i believe so)

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Note that full_clean() will not be called automatically when you call
>   your model’s save() method. You’ll need to call it manually when you
>   want to run one-step model validation for your own manually created
>   models. [[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)]

This is apparently done for backwards compatibility reasons, check [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13100) ticket out.

Model's `full_clean()` method is responsible for calling `Model.clean()`, but because it's never been called, your clean method inside model is basically omitted.

You can do couple of things for this. You can call model's clean manually. Or, you can move your validation logic into **ModelForm** using its clean methods. If you are mainly creating instance via form, I think it's the best place to perform validation (and more common practice).

Try this:

```
class LeaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LeaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['unit'].required = True


    # IF your validation logic includes multiple fields override this
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LeaseForm, self).clean()
        # .. your logic 
        return cleaned_data

    # IF just your field's value is enough for validation override this
    def clean__unit(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('unit', None)
        # .. your logic 
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Lease
        fields = [  'unit',
        'is_active','is_renewed', 'description']
```